# How do I sort an array of ints in cocoa?

Tags: arrays, cocoa

I'm brand new to programming on the Mac (i.e. xcode and cocoa) and I'm trying to simply perform a bubble sort and am having a lot of difficulty with this.

The goal of this is to filter an image using a median filter by using a 9 pixel kernel. I take in the grey scale values of all nine pixels and then I'm trying to put them in a nine point array and sort the array to extract the median value of the nine (so it doesn't matter if I use ascending or descending).

I've been trying to store the pixel values (which are ints) into a `NSMutableArray` but I really have no idea how to go about doing this or how to then sort them when the array is populated.

```
    // Perform median filter on all images in the stack 
    for (x = 0; x < [curPix pwidth]; x++){
        for (y = 0; y < [curPix pheight]; y++){

            float value;
            int tLeft, tMid, tRight, cLeft, index, cRight, bLeft, bMid, bRight; // takes in pixel placement
            value = tLeft = tMid = tRight = cLeft = index = cRight = bLeft = bMid = bRight = 0;
            curPos = y * [curPix pwidth] + x;

            if (x != 0 && y != 0 && x != ([curPix pwidth]-1) && y != ([curPix pheight]-1)){

                //Make kernel for median filter
                index   = fImage[curPos];                       // index pixel
                tLeft   = fImage[index - [curPix pwidth] - 1];  // top left
                tMid    = fImage[index - [curPix pwidth]];      // top middle
                tRight  = fImage[index - [curPix pwidth] + 1];  // top right
                cLeft   = fImage[index - 1];                    // center left
                cRight  = fImage[index + 1];                    // center right
                bLeft   = fImage[index + [curPix pwidth] - 1];  // bottom left
                bMid    = fImage[index + [curPix pwidth]];      // bottom middle
                bRight  = fImage[index + [curPix pwidth] + 1];  // bottom right

                // Need to make array, populate with pixels (above), and sort.
                // Once sorted, take median value, save it as 'value', and store it as new pixel value

                fImage[curPos] = (int) value;   // return value to index
            }
            else {
                fImage[curPos] = fImage[curPos];                
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> How do I sort an array of ints in cocoa?

`int` is a C type, so, the same way as in C.

Mac OS X comes with a number of sort functions in the standard library. `qsort`, which is Quicksort, is defined by C; the others come, I think, from BSD. They're all under [qsort's manpage](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/qsort.3.html).

Each of the functions takes an array of pointer-sized elements, so you'll want to use `long` (or, for more portability, `intptr_t`), not `int`, for the elements.

Make a C array of such elements, fill it out manually, then sort with one of these functions and find the median.

Answer (score 1):

To fill them into an `NS(Mutable)Array` you need to wrap your `int`s in instances of `NSNumber`, e.g.:

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray array];
[myArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:42]];
```

There are various methods to sort the resulting array, to get you started:

```
[myArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Fortunately, this doesn't use BubbleSort.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with I would steer away from bubble sorts unless you are sorting a small sample. Bubble sort is very slow. Not being a cocoa expert I can't really help you very much other than suggesting you look into the built in array sorting routines.

This is for the iphone but might help:
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/61615-how-do-i-sort-30-000-objects.html

Good luck.

Comment: That's for sorting Cocoa objects, not `int`s.